# .NET - How to parse an URL and then build a new URL from it?

Tags: parsing, url, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

I read the return URL from the request and then I want to redirect the user to this site. Getting a part of the URL is not the problem, but I don't know how to work with the parameters afterward.

I currently have:

```
var previous = Request.Query["ReturnUrl"].ToString().TrimStart('/');
var path = previous.Split("/");

if (Url.IsLocalUrl(url))
{
    return RedirectToAction(path[0], path[1]);
}
```

I now will have an array with `(Controller, Action+Params)`. The above is fine when I only have the controller + action (`Home/Index`), but when I have something with parameters, it will not work. (`Home/Index?id=123`, `Home/Index?id=123&action=nothing`, `www.mysite.com`, etc).

How can I properly parse this and then use it for a redirect? Or is it possible to read the full `ReturnUrl` and then use this as a redirect? I haven't found a way how to do this either.

I have found the `QueryString` class, but for this, I have to first parse the incoming URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

> but when I have something with Parameters, it will not work.

Do you want something like this?

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Privacy", new { id = 1 });    
}

public IActionResult Privacy(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but for this I first have to parse the Parameters of my Returnurl, no? Or is there an way to just copy the full Parameters of the given URL and then redirect to there?

Comment: @SuperNev  Do you want `return Redirect("https://localhost:7090/Home/Privacy/1");` ?

Comment: @SuperNev  OR `return Redirect("https://localhost:7090/Home/Privacy?id=1&name=aa");` ? like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cZU4.png

Comment: My Actions look like in the 2nd example.... And I did not know that I can use Redirect with an complete URL.... Is it also possible to get the full URL from the ReturnUrl? Otherwise I just can use the Request.Host/Scheme/etc to build it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request.QueryString` method like this:

```cs
string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];

if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```